# Using @media in css of HTML Email

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a HTML email to print a table at a lesser width than it looks on screen.  I've put in:

```
@media print{
  .style1 {
    width: 500;
  }
}
```

When I print it still runs off the page.  I've set it to a ridiculously small amount with no avail.  The `style1` is applied to a table which has a width of 100%, I thought the percent might be throwing it so I changed it to a width of `688` and got the same results.  there are no rows or cells that have a fixed width in the table; they all use percents.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that is a direct example above, you need to provide a unit (px, em, etc.) for any values other than 0 in css definitions:

```
@media print{
  .style1 {
    width: 500px;
  }
}
```

This differs from the html attributes which assumes pixels. Hope this helps, -Matt

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should define a unit after the width. Most browsers still use pixel units as a failsafe though, so chance is this is not the actual problem.

What mailclient are you using?

[Support for print CSS is not guaranteed across different mailclients.](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/1907/can-i-include-a-print-styleshe/)